# shopping cart in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Hi I am new with ajax and having problem. I am trying to make a shopping cart using ajax.I don't know what is wrong with my code please help me out.
When I click the add button an alert comes 'No success' and nothing happen , I am not able add items to cart.
Thanks for helping me.

This is my view

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Codeigniter cart class</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var insert_data= $(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
        url:  "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/shopping2/add",  
        dataType: 'json',
        //type: "POST",
        data: insert_data,

            success:function(response) {

//if (response){
   //var res = JSON.parse(response);
    var res = response;
    if(res.status == 200){

        window.location.href="http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_cart2/index.php/shopping2";
    }else{

        alert(res.msg);
    }
//}
//else{ 
   // alert('sorry');
//}
                }

});
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


  <div id='content'>
    <div class="row"> 

    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <h2 align="center">Items</h2>
        <?php


        ?>

                 <table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px">

        <?php
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $id = $product['serial'];
            $name = $product['name'];

            $price = $product['price'];
            ?>


                  <tr class="well">
                 <td style="padding-left:15px;"><?php echo $name; ?></td>

                    <td>
                        Rs. <?php echo $price; ?></td>
                    <?php
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    echo form_open('',array('id' => 'myform'));
                    echo form_hidden('id', $id);
                    echo form_hidden('name', $name);
                    echo form_hidden('price', $price);
                    ?> <!--</div>--> 

                    <?php
                    $btn = array(
                        'class' => 'fg-button teal',
                        'value' => 'Add',
                        'name' => 'action',
                        'id' => 'add_button'
                    );
                    ?>
                   <td>
                    <?php
                    // Submit Button.
                    echo form_submit($btn);
                    echo form_close();
                    ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </table>

                </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
   <!-- <div id="cart" >-->

            <h2 align="center">Items on  Cart</h2>


            <div> 
        <?php  $cart_check = $this->cart->contents();


         if(empty($cart_check)) {
         echo 'To add products to your shopping cart click on "Add" Button'; 
         }  ?> </div>

            <table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px">
              <?php
              // All values of cart store in "$cart". 
              if ($cart = $this->cart->contents()): ?>
                <div id="addcart">
                <tr id= "main_heading" class="well">

                    <td style="padding-left:15px;"><?>Name</td>
                    <td>Price(Rs)</td>
                    <td>Qty</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Remove</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                 // Create form and send all values in "shopping/update_cart" function.
                echo form_open('shopping2/update_cart');
                $grand_total = 0;
                $i = 1;

                foreach ($cart as $item):


                    echo form_hidden('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][id]', $item['id']);
                    echo form_hidden('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][rowid]', $item['rowid']);
                    echo form_hidden('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][name]', $item['name']);
                    echo form_hidden('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][price]', $item['price']);
                    echo form_hidden('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]', $item['qty']);
                    ?>
                    <tr class="well" id="addcart">

                        <td style="padding-left:15px;">
                  <?php echo $item['name']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?php echo form_input('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]', $item['qty'], ' type="number" max="99" min="1" value="1" style="width:50px;"'); ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php $grand_total = $grand_total + $item['subtotal']; ?>
                        <td>
                            Rs <?php echo number_format($item['subtotal'], 2) ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        <?php 
                        // cancle image.
                        $path = "<img src='http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_cart2/images/cart_cross.jpg' width='25px' height='20px'>";
                        echo anchor('shopping/remove/' . $item['rowid'], $path); ?>
                        </td>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:30px;"><b>Order Total: Rs <?php 

                    //Grand Total.
                    echo number_format($grand_total, 2); ?></b></td>


                    <td colspan="5" align="right"><input type="button" class ='fg-button teal' value="Clear cart" onclick="window.location = 'shopping2/remove'">

                        <?php //submit button. ?>
                        <input type="submit" class ='fg-button teal' value="Update Cart">
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>


                        </td>
                </tr></div>
<?php endif; ?>
        </table>


    </div>


   <!-- <div id="products_e" align="center">-->

            <!--</div>-->



   <!-- </div>-->
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Shopping2 extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //load model
    $this->load->model('billing_model');
            $this->load->library('cart');
}

public function index()
{   

    $data['products'] = $this->billing_model->get_all();

    $this->load->view('shopping_view2', $data);
}
function add()
{
        $insert_data = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'qty' => 1
    );  

    $this->cart->insert($insert_data);
   //$success = $this->cart->insert($insert_data);
     $cart_check = $this->cart->contents();

 if(!empty($cart_check)){ 
    //$this->cart->contents(insert_data);
    $res = array('status' => 200, 'msg' => 'success');

}else{
    $res = array('status' => 500, 'msg' => 'No success');
}

echo json_encode($res);
//echo $data[0]['value'];
//redirect('shopping2');
}


    function remove($rowid) {
                // Check rowid value.
    if ($rowid==="all"){

        $this->cart->destroy();
    }else{

        $data = array(
            'rowid'   => $rowid,
            'qty'     => 0
        );

        $this->cart->update($data);
    }


    redirect('shopping2');
}

    function update_cart(){

            // Recieve post values,calcute them and update
            $cart_info =  $_POST['cart'] ;
    foreach( $cart_info as $id => $cart)
    {   
                $rowid = $cart['rowid'];
                $price = $cart['price'];
                $amount = $price * $cart['qty'];
                $qty = $cart['qty'];

                    $data = array(
            'rowid'   => $rowid,
                            'price'   => $price,
                            'amount' =>  $amount,
            'qty'     => $qty
        );

        $this->cart->update($data);
    }
    redirect('shopping2');        
}   

}
```

Please help me how to add items in the cart using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Since u managed to get a response, the problem should lie in your Model or data insertion.

Few suggestions:

1. It's also recommended that you use $.post() instead of $.ajax().
2. `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/shopping2/add"` can be changed to `"<?php echo site_url('shopping2/add"'); ?>"`
3. Use the built in Codeignter output class to output your JSON. See here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html

Comment: I think i hav e problem in data insertion so how should I overcome it ?

Comment: There are many possibilities why the data is not inserted. So you should start narrowing down what could be wrong. First thing to check, are your sessions working? The built in cart library uses sessions.

Answer (score 0):

### word

```
function update_cart(){

    // Receive post values,calculate them and update
    $cart_info =  $_POST['cart'] ;
    foreach( $cart_info as $id => $cart)
    {   
                $rowid = $cart['rowid'];
                $price = $cart['price'];
                $amount = $price * $cart['qty'];
                $qty = $cart['qty'];

                    $data = array(
            'rowid'   => $rowid,
                            'price'   => $price,
                            'amount' =>  $amount,
            'qty'     => $qty
        );

        $this->cart->update($data);
    }
    redirect('shopping2');        
}   

}
```